# Which suitable plot for this Data in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization

I m a beginner in data visualization in R, I would like to plot this data in the way that for every country it shows meat, beef, and fish consumption over years in the same plot, which type of plot could be suitable?

```
df <- data.frame(country=c("Italy", "France", "Germany","Italy", "France", "Germany","Italy", "France", "Germany","Italy", "France", "Germany"),
                 years=c(1992, 1992, 1992,1995,1995,1995,1997,1997,1997,1999,1999,1999),
                 meat=c(7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18),
                 beef=c(70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180),
                 fish=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I voted to close this question since I think this leads to an opinion-based answer. Nevertheless, you could use `ggplot2` and plot the consumptions per year and product for every country:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(c("meat", "beef", "fish")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=years, y=value, color=name)) +
  geom_path() + 
  facet_wrap(~ country) + 
  labs(title = "Meat, beef, and fish consumption over years per country")
```

gives you

[image]

If you want to use `ggplot2`, take a look at [Top 50 ggplot2 Visualizations - The Master List (With Full R Code)](http://r-statistics.co/Top50-Ggplot2-Visualizations-MasterList-R-Code.html) for plotting examples. Choose the plot **you** think is suitable.

**EDIT**

If you want to plot all countries into one plot and distinguish them with different linetypes, you could use

```r
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(c("meat", "beef", "fish")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=years, y=value, color=name)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=country)) + 
  labs(title = "Meat, beef, and fish consumption over years per country")
```

If all countries should be aggregated, remove the `aes(linetype=country)` of `geom_line()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually, I would like that all countries must be on the same plot.

Comment: Added a new solution.